# Open Atrium Space and Group parent relationship

Tags: organic-groups, distributions

I'm looking for documentation (or just advice) on setting up Space - Group parent relationships for [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium). I've viewed a number of [Open Atrium webinars](https://www.drupal.org/node/2290219) and sifted through documentation, but surprisingly, I haven't found much on this specific topic. Most of what I've found simply refers to group members of spaces, but that does not (as far as I can tell) imply anything about how exactly that membership is configured. An example is this [Building Blocks + Case Study PDF](http://docs.openatrium.com/system/files/oa2_terminology_and_privacy.pdf).

For most use cases, it seems to make sense that top-level groups would be the parents of spaces, with something like the following:

Group 1

-Space 1

-Space 2

--Sub-space

Group 2

-Space 1

-Space 3

Are there use cases for having the spaces as parents? What are the implications for user permissions and access control inheritance?